# Question: tag creation after retagging

Tags: support, tags

Situation:
I've achieved the 150 rep on site yesterday and decided to retag [my question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/soft-sound-strings-for-fender-bass) to create and add the [5-string-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5-string-bass-guitar) tag. Unfortunately, I've misspelled it, and added the [5-strings-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5-strings-bass-guitar) tag (English is not my native language). After that, my question was [revised](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/2966/revisions) and retagged.
Question:
Who is the creator of the new tag [5-string-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5-string-bass-guitar)? Me or my revisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rshallit created [5-string-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5-string-bass-guitar).

Does it matter?

Comment: I was dreaming about add a new tag to this site, and now I'm very sad about my English problem. I hoped this new tag will sometime achieved the 50-questions :)

Comment: @VMAtm: I'm sorry to have stolen it...

Comment: Well, I'm gonna improve my English. That happens :)